# Ubuntu 20.04 gradle `could not get resource`

Tags: ubuntu, gradle

Я недавно скачал Gradle на Ubuntu 20.04. При постройке файла вылезает вот такая ошибка:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
  > Could not resolve com.github.Anuken.Arc:arc-core:master-SNAPSHOT.
Required by: project:
  > Could not resolve com.github.Anuken.Arc:arc-core:master-SNAPSHOT.
  > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/Anuken/Arc/arc-core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
  > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/Anuken/Arc/arc-core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/Anuken/Arc/arc-core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
  > Could not resolve com.github.Anuken.Arc:arc-core:master-SNAPSHOT.
  > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/com/github/Anuken/Arc/arc-core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
  > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/Anuken/Arc/arc-core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/Anuken/Arc/arc-core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
  > Could not resolve com.github.Anuken.Mindustry:core:master-SNAPSHOT.
Required by: project:
  > Could not resolve com.github.Anuken.Mindustry:core:master-SNAPSHOT.
  > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/Anuken/Mindustry/core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
  > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/Anuken/Mindustry/core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/Anuken/Mindustry/core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
  > Could not resolve com.github.Anuken.Mindustry:core:master-SNAPSHOT.
  > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/com/github/Anuken/Mindustry/core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
  > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/Anuken/Mindustry/core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/Anuken/Mindustry/core/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Можете помочь мне с исправлением ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, что проблема не в Gradle, а в Java, которая используется на вашем компьютере.

Из текста ошибки видно, что Java не может получить файл через HTTPS.

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

При поиске по данной ошибке я наткнулся на данный ответ. Он для Ubuntu 18.04, но, возможно, поможет и Вам.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103533/9978153

Кажется, дело в том, что вам нужно обновить\заменить keystore.